Jest mock an imported function - it keeps calling the original
I have a function in a module segmentEvents.ts and I want to assert that another function is called when I call the first. The problem is that I am unable to mock the second function to check it's called.  No matter what I do the real implementation of the function is called.
What am I doing wrong here? How do I mock trackEvent?
Here is my code, all files in the same directory
test.spec.ts
jest.mock('./segment', () => ({
  trackEvent: jest.fn(),
}));

import { expect } from '@jest/globals';
import eventHandlers from './segmentEvents';
import { trackEvent } from './segment';

describe('Segment Events', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });

  it('should call trackEvent when someEvent is invoked', () => {
    console.log('trackEvent', trackEvent); // is supposed to be a mock function but it's not

    eventHandlers.someEvent();

    expect(trackEvent).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});

segmentEvents.ts
import { trackEvent } from "./segment";

function mealPlanSelected(): void {
  trackEvent();
}

const eventHandlers = {
  mealPlanSelected,
};

export default eventHandlers;

src/utils/segment.ts
export const trackEvent = (): String => {
  console.log("***Event Tracked***");
  return 'test';
}



Please give a [mre] - if you're trying to use ESM, for example, see https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules#module-mocking-in-esm.

console.log('trackEvent', trackEvent); // is supposed to be a mock function but it's not - why did you console.log a function? what's your expectd result and what's the actual result you got? by the way, your code can not compile, you should provide a runable example.
